# Can I use Regular Expressions in USQL?

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql

Is it possible to write regular expression comparisons in USQL?

For example, rather than multiple "LIKE" statements to search for the name of various food items, I want to perform a comparison of multiple items using a single Regex expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new Regex object inline and then use the IsMatch() method.

The example below returns "Y" if the Offer_Desc column contains the word "bacon", "croissant", or "panini".

```
@output =
SELECT 
    , CSHARP(new Regex("\\b(BACON|CROISSANT|PANINI)S?\\b"
             )).IsMatch(wrk.Offer_Desc.ToUpper())
      ? "Y"
      : "N" AS Is_Food
FROM ... AS wrk
```

Notes:

- The CSHARP() block is optional, but you do need to escape any backslashes in your regex by doubling them (as in the example above).
- The regex sample accepts these as a single words, either in singular or plural form ("paninis" is okay but "baconator" is not).

Comment: Please note that if you use very complex regex patterns, you should avoid using the regex compilation option, since there is a performance bug in the .Net Framework 4.5.2 version that U-SQL currently uses in ADLA.

Comment: @MichaelRys Good to know, but I'm not sure what you mean by the compilation option. Can you give an example or a link with more info?

Comment: Here is a general best practice article on Regex in .Net: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/best-practices. Note that this article recommends to use compiled Regex, but as I mentioned above, for some expressions with .Net 4.5.2, this is actually a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

I'd assume it would be the same inline, but when I used regex in code behind I hit some show-stopping speed issues.

If you are checking a reasonable number of food items I'd really recommend just using an inline ternary statement to get the results you're looking for.

```
@output =
SELECT 
    wrk.Offer_Desc.ToLowerInvariant() == "bacon" || 
    wrk.Offer_Desc.ToLowerInvariant() == "croissant" || 
    wrk.Offer_Desc.ToLowerInvariant() == "panini" ? "Y" : "N" AS Is_Food
FROM ... AS wrk
```

If you do need to check if a string *contains* a string, the string Contains method might still be a better approach.

```
@output =
    SELECT 
        wrk.Offer_Desc.ToLowerInvariant().Contains("bacon") || 
        wrk.Offer_Desc.ToLowerInvariant().Contains("croissant") || 
        wrk.Offer_Desc.ToLowerInvariant().Contains("panini") ? "Y" : "N" AS Is_Food
    FROM ... AS wrk
```