# How can I extract a substring based on a regex in U-SQL?

Tags: u-sql

I am trying to extract some substring based on a regex in U-SQL. But I couldn't find a built-in function to do so.
Maybe there is even an easier way to solve my problem.
I have version codes like "1.10.12 ABC" or "10.1" or "10.1.10" and want to standardize them in a way that I only get the first two numbers.
So something like `"^\d+\.\d+"` in regex.

Is there a way to get that result in U-SQL?

```
@someData =
SELECT * FROM
    ( VALUES
    ("1.1.10 ABC"),
    ("1.10.1"),
    ("15.3.2")
    ) AS T(version);
```

I want the versions in the following format:

```
"1.1"
"1.10"
"15.3"
```

Comment: do you need to extract or just select those versions?

Comment: I need to extract them. Basically I want a new column containing the standardized values

Comment: see my answer, if that helps

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use Regular Expressions in USQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50298468/can-i-use-regular-expressions-in-usql)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
@someData =
SELECT * FROM
    ( VALUES
    (Regex.Replace("1.1.10 ABC", "^\d+\.\d+"),
    (Regex.Replace("1.10.1", "^\d+\.\d+"),
    (Regex.Replace("15.3.2", "^\d+\.\d+")
    ) AS T(version);
```